# When using OnePress, can I change the font of toppage?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Currently, I create a homepage using OnePress's free version.
I have the following questions regarding changing font design.
Question
I do not know how to change the font design in the area A of the image.

Although you can change the font design in area B,
I do not know how to change font design in areaA.
With OnePress's free version, is the specification that you can not change font design in areaA?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mX9i.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change it even in the free version by css. Try adding this to the end of style.css

```
h2.hero-large-text{
    font-family: "impact";
}
```

Replace the font family with a font of your liking. Let me know if this helped!

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I tried looking for a solution for a long time but I could not find a solution.
It was very helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped!